# Create a Mail account for the user

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, email

is there a way (API) to create and setup a mail account for a user if he provides his login data? Let's Say his account is bla@fake.de and the pw 1234. If I know the provider, can I do the setup for him? Its possible in android, but I doubt it is in iOS due to apple's policy.

If anyone knows about a way to do this I'd appreciate it if he could direct me to some ressources on how to accomplish this.

Comment: You mentioned "Create a Mail account for the user" is possible in android. Can you give some samples to do this? I have posted my question in this link([question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480337/android-createor-register-new-pop3-email-account-in-rouncube-mail-server)). Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public on-device API to achieve this. A possible solution might be to have your server create a [configuration profile](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206) that you’d [deliver over the air](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009505). Of course, this approach makes sense only if you have control over the mail service in question.

Comment: well what exactly do yoou mean with "have control"?

Comment: Say you want to configure an account for `john.doe@example.com`. Then you should be the one operating *example.com* (not you personally but the company you create the app for). This is because the profile should be created and signed by a server, not by your app. If your app created configuration profiles for, say, *hotmail.com* but you were the operator of *example.com* the user would have to send their *hotmail.com* account information to a third-party service (*example.com*). This isn’t a technical issue, but it might be a trust issue.