# How to Create (or Register) new pop3 email account in my mail server

Tags: android, pop3, mail-server

I am creating one android application which will have API to create a new pop3 email account. I am using roundcube webmail client to create new email account(Manually). But I need to create new account programatically. I have searched over the internet. But I didn't get any samples. Can anyone give some hints or samples to create(or Register) new pop3 email account in android.

My question is similar like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560247/create-email-account-from-type-existing-account-services).

My aim is to create new email account to any mail server. I know the API for the each and every mail server has different one. Can I create the generic API to create new email account for any mail server?

Comment: maybe this can  help you http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html

Comment: Thanks. But this link provides access to a POP3 message store from an existing POP3 account. But I need to create new POP3 account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you control the email server or have found one that permits this I don't think you can do what you are asking. Most 'public' pop3 servers block this sort of thing to prevent spammers from creating accounts. Sites like Yahoo, GMail, etc use captchas and the like just for this reason.

[Create gmail, facebook and twitter account through API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956050/create-gmail-facebook-and-twitter-account-through-api)

You could implement this on a v limited basis if you had a trusted relationship with some specific email providers but aiming to create email accounts anywhere via API isn't going to get v far.